# How to decrease anime time when it is out of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a anime whose duration decreases when the black container crosses red, but this creates glitches. Can there be any method to remove the glitch in it.

I tried to delay the changes until path is completed by red but still faces the glitches.

```
delayInAnimeSub = ourVillanAnimeDuration * (ourVillanFigXValue / window.innerWidth)
animeDelayAmount = Math.abs(delayInAnimeSub.toFixed(2) - 0.2).toFixed(2);
```

I calculated the leftover distance of red from the left side and get the duration to complete that distance and added that to delay. But it still show glitches.

> Here what happens in below snippet
>
> > - Black box is hero which is controlled by `space`(to jump), `<`(to move left), `>`(to move right).
> > - Red is villan(demon) which have animation to move from right side to left side with some duration in animation.
> > - Whenever hero passes the red, red becomes faster(by trying to reduce animation duration), but with this red has glitches and start from anywhere(not from the place it should be next).
> >
> > > - I want to increase speed of red but facing the glitches so tried to delay the change in animation duration until red crosses the screen but that didn't seems to work

```js
let ourHeroFig = document.getElementById("ourHero");
let ourVillanFig = document.getElementById("obstacleBar");
let gameScoreDigits = document.getElementById("gameScoreDigits");
let valueXCoordinate = "";
let obstacleBarCrossed = true;

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  let ourHeroFigXValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('left'));
  let ourHeroFigYValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('bottom'));
  if (e.code === "ArrowRight") {
    valueXCoordinate = ourHeroFigXValue + 100;

  } else if (e.code === "KeyA" || e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
    if (ourHeroFigXValue > ourHeroFig.offsetWidth + 90) {
      valueXCoordinate = ourHeroFigXValue - 100;
    } else {
      valueXCoordinate = 0;
    }
  } else if (e.code === "Space") {
    ourHeroFig.classList.add("animateHero");
    setTimeout(function() {
      ourHeroFig.classList.remove("animateHero");
    }, 700)
  }
  changePosition();

})

function changePosition() {
  ourHeroFig.style.left = valueXCoordinate + 'px'
}

let delayInAnimeSub = ""
setInterval(
  function() {
    let ourHeroFigXValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('left'));
    let ourHeroFigYValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('bottom'));
    let ourVillanFigXValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourVillanFig).getPropertyValue('left'));
    let ourVillanFigYValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourVillanFig).getPropertyValue('bottom'));
    let gameOverValueX = Math.abs(ourVillanFigXValue - ourHeroFigXValue);
    let gameOverValueY = Math.abs(ourVillanFigYValue - ourHeroFigYValue);

    if (gameOverValueX < ourVillanFig.offsetWidth && gameOverValueY < ourVillanFig.offsetHeight) {
      console.log("yes touched");
      ourVillanFig.classList.remove("animateVillan");
      obstacleBarCrossed = false;
    } else if (obstacleBarCrossed && gameOverValueX < ourVillanFig.offsetWidth) {
      ourVillanAnimeDuration = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(ourVillanFig).getPropertyValue('animation-duration'));
      delayInAnimeSub = ourVillanAnimeDuration * (ourVillanFigXValue / window.innerWidth)
      animeDelayAmount = Math.abs(delayInAnimeSub.toFixed(2) - 0.2).toFixed(2);
      console.log(animeDelayAmount, ourVillanAnimeDuration, ourVillanFigXValue)
      if (ourVillanAnimeDuration <= 2) {
        ourVillanAnimeDuration = 2
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        ourVillanFig.style.animationDuration = ourVillanAnimeDuration - 0.1 + "s";
      }, animeDelayAmount);
    }
    // console.log(gameOverValueX,gameOverValueY)
  }, 10);
```

```css
#ourHero {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.animateHero {
  animation: animateHero 0.7s linear;
}

@keyframes animateHero {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 350px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

#obstacleBar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50vw;
}

.animateVillan {
  animation: animateVillan 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animateVillan {
  0% {
    left: 110vw;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ourHero"></div>
<div id="obstacleBar" class="animateVillan"></div>
```

**Thanks for help in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [Animation.playbackRate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/playbackRate) but it is still experimental.

```
let VillRate = 1
...

// inside the collision check

if (VillRate < 20) {
  ourVillanFig.getAnimations()[0].playbackRate += 0.2
  VillRate += 0.5
}
```

In the below snippet, red speed will increase untill a certain point everytime it touches black. You can adjust that behavior as you need.

```js
let ourHeroFig = document.getElementById('ourHero')
let ourVillanFig = document.getElementById('obstacleBar')
let gameScoreDigits = document.getElementById('gameScoreDigits')
let valueXCoordinate = ''
let obstacleBarCrossed = true

let VillRate = 1

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  let ourHeroFigXValue = parseInt(
    getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('left')
  )
  let ourHeroFigYValue = parseInt(
    getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('bottom')
  )
  if (e.code === 'ArrowRight') {
    valueXCoordinate = ourHeroFigXValue + 100
  } else if (e.code === 'KeyA' || e.code === 'ArrowLeft') {
    if (ourHeroFigXValue > ourHeroFig.offsetWidth + 90) {
      valueXCoordinate = ourHeroFigXValue - 100
    } else {
      valueXCoordinate = 0
    }
  } else if (e.code === 'Space') {
    ourHeroFig.classList.add('animateHero')
    setTimeout(function() {
      ourHeroFig.classList.remove('animateHero')
    }, 700)
  }
  changePosition()
})

function changePosition() {
  ourHeroFig.style.left = valueXCoordinate + 'px'
}

let delayInAnimeSub = ''
setInterval(function() {
  let ourHeroFigXValue = parseInt(
    getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('left')
  )
  let ourHeroFigYValue = parseInt(
    getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('bottom')
  )
  let ourVillanFigXValue = parseInt(
    getComputedStyle(ourVillanFig).getPropertyValue('left')
  )
  let ourVillanFigYValue = parseInt(
    getComputedStyle(ourVillanFig).getPropertyValue('bottom')
  )
  let gameOverValueX = Math.abs(ourVillanFigXValue - ourHeroFigXValue)
  let gameOverValueY = Math.abs(ourVillanFigYValue - ourHeroFigYValue)

  if (
    gameOverValueX < ourVillanFig.offsetWidth &&
    gameOverValueY < ourVillanFig.offsetHeight
  ) {
    if (VillRate < 20) {
      ourVillanFig.getAnimations()[0].playbackRate += 0.2
      VillRate += 0.5
    }
  }
}, 10)
```

```css
#ourHero {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.animateHero {
  animation: animateHero 0.7s linear;
}

@keyframes animateHero {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 350px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

#obstacleBar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50vw;
}

.animateVillan {
  animation: animateVillan 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animateVillan {
  0% {
    left: 110vw;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ourHero"></div>
<div id="obstacleBar" class="animateVillan"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
 if (ourVillanFigXValue < 10) {
    ourVillanFig.style.animationDuration = ourVillanAnimeDuration - 0.1 + "s";
  }
```

It works ok but when time get reduced to `4s` and after it, the red don't start from the end but start in between. Almost start from middle at `3s`

```js
let ourHeroFig = document.getElementById("ourHero");
let ourVillanFig = document.getElementById("obstacleBar");
let gameScoreDigits = document.getElementById("gameScoreDigits");
let valueXCoordinate = "";
let obstacleBarCrossed = true;

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  let ourHeroFigXValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('left'));
  let ourHeroFigYValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('bottom'));

  if (e.code === "ArrowRight") {
    valueXCoordinate = ourHeroFigXValue + 100;

  } else if (e.code === "KeyA" || e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
    if (ourHeroFigXValue > ourHeroFig.offsetWidth + 90) {
      valueXCoordinate = ourHeroFigXValue - 100;
    } else {
      valueXCoordinate = 0;
    }
  } else if (e.code === "Space") {
    ourHeroFig.classList.add("animateHero");
    setTimeout(function() {
      ourHeroFig.classList.remove("animateHero");
    }, 700)
  }
  changePosition();

})

function changePosition() {
  ourHeroFig.style.left = valueXCoordinate + 'px'
}

let delayInAnimeSub = ""
setInterval(
  function() {
    let ourHeroFigXValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('left'));
    let ourHeroFigYValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourHeroFig).getPropertyValue('bottom'));
    let ourVillanFigXValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourVillanFig).getPropertyValue('left'));
    let ourVillanFigYValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(ourVillanFig).getPropertyValue('bottom'));
    let gameOverValueX = Math.abs(ourVillanFigXValue - ourHeroFigXValue);
    let gameOverValueY = Math.abs(ourVillanFigYValue - ourHeroFigYValue);

    if (ourVillanFigXValue < 10) {
      ourVillanFig.style.animationDuration = ourVillanAnimeDuration - 0.1 + "s";
    }
    if (gameOverValueX < ourVillanFig.offsetWidth && gameOverValueY < ourVillanFig.offsetHeight) {
      console.log("yes touched");
      ourVillanFig.classList.remove("animateVillan");
      obstacleBarCrossed = false;
    } else if (obstacleBarCrossed && gameOverValueX < ourVillanFig.offsetWidth) {
      ourVillanAnimeDuration = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(ourVillanFig).getPropertyValue('animation-duration'));
      console.log(ourVillanFigXValue < 0, ourVillanAnimeDuration)

      if (ourVillanAnimeDuration <= 2) {
        ourVillanAnimeDuration = 2
      }
    }
    // console.log(gameOverValueX,gameOverValueY)
  }, 10);
```

```css
#ourHero {
  width: 20px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.animateHero {
  animation: animateHero 0.7s linear;
}

@keyframes animateHero {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 350px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

#obstacleBar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50vw;
}

.animateVillan {
  animation: animateVillan 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animateVillan {
  0% {
    left: 110vw;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ourHero"></div>
<div id="obstacleBar" class="animateVillan"></div>
```